# Getting different page layout on 127.0.0.1 and localhost

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, mozilla

I'm trying to make a responsive website on my laptop. I'm using live reload at `0.0.0.0` port 3000 so that I can watch my project in my mobile device also but I'm getting this weird problem. When I view my project at `127.0.0.1` I'm getting the layout below:

[image: picture when viewed at 127.0.0.1]

but when I view my website at `localhost` or `192.168.0.102` or `0.0.0.0` I get the below layout:

[image]

Below is the pic from Chrome on 127.0.0.1

[image]

I have no idea why this is happening. I have used:

1. Zurb Foundation 5
2. Bourbon

Comment: Are you sure you just haven't zoomed in when visiting the unique address 127.0.0.1? Zooming in with mozilla is remembered by the particular URI, not the code base.

Comment: If you check the Network tab of the developer tools, do you see anything different?

Comment: Thanks @ham-sandwich. i so dumb....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you zoom in, you are zooming in on one page and only one page - not the particular code base. It is likely you adjusted the browser window when visiting **127.0.0.1**. Go to **View >> Zoom >> Reset**

Answer (score 0):

Check the Address Bar of the page that looks smaller, you should see a Search Bar like the one in blue circle.

[image: Search Bar]

Click and on it, you should have a **Reset** button dialog, Click on the **Reset Button**.
The search Icon should disappear now.