# Svelte scales differently depending on my IP

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have an issue which i can't even seem to find a path to dig in

If i'm working with http://localhost:5173 there is no issues, but once i change url to any ip (eg. 127.0.0.1:5173), size of website suddenly increases.[image][image]

Expected behaviour: i want to page look like with http://localhost:5173

Comment: make sure css files are loading. Sometime due to different origin localhost vs 127.0.0.1 some file might not load. Try to check from devtools if css is being applied or not.

Comment: im a clown. Found solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726819/getting-different-page-layout-on-127-0-0-1-and-localhost